# Raspberry Pi official Display

Tags: python, display, tkinter

I bought the official Raspberry Pi Display and wonder now how I can display a GUI on it. I‘m using Raspbian with desktop. I did a lot of research and tried to make an Autostart Programm, which shows a tkinter GUI. But this didn‘t work out so well. What‘s the best way to display a self made GUI( with python tkinter) on the display. I have no big raspberry Pi experience so beginner friendly explanations would be perfect.

Comment: please add an explanation why `But this didn‘t work out so well.`

Comment: I didn‘t managed it to autostart and the GUI wasn‘t hiding e.g the Taskbar. I wanted that you plug in the Pi and you only see the GUI and not Raspbian. There are so many projects, which uses the Display in the way i want so I thought it wouldn’t be so difficult.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest GUI is guizero. To install:

```
pip3 install guizero
```

Simple example:

```
from guizero import App

app = App(title="Hello world")

app.display()
```

[image]

https://lawsie.github.io/guizero/start/

One method to autostart:

```
sudo thonny /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart
```

Add:

```
@python3 /home/pi/test.py
```